# Cannot interact IBOutlet on CustomView Xib Files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

I'm a Swift beginner, and I'm stacking on using CustomView Xib Files on Swift.

I have five CustomViews, named HogeAView~HogeEView respectively.

From HogeAView to HogeCView, the view can loaded without describing any errors, and enabled to  interact all outlets which I placed.

But HogeDView and HogeEView, that made same way as other three views are not working.
Both Views are loaded, but all outlets which I placed returns no responses when I interacted.
(e.g. UIButton doesn't make a flash when the button was pressed)

I confirmed Files'owner UIViewClass is correct, same name as written in Code, and there's no absurd Views which prevents interacting.

Please give me a solution if you know how to solve the problem.

Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class HogeDView: UIView {
 
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadNib()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        loadNib()
    }

    func loadNib(){
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HogeDView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
    }
    
}
```

```
import UIKit

class HogeDViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view = HogeDView()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXvYG.png)

- Filled HogeDView class in the **File's owner **, not in the view of the hierarchy in Xid Files.
- Retried making HogeDview, and HogeDController.
- Confirmed there is no absurd view upper front.
- Confirmed UIConnection is Correct

Comment: *"`self.view = HogeDView()`"* --Why are you trying to replace the **view controller's** view? I would expect you want to add an instance of `HogeDView` as a ***subview***.

Comment: @DonMag That line would make sense if it was put as the only line (don't call `super.loadView()`) in `loadView` instead of having it in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

My first code was a copy of online tutorial...and it should had to be worked correctly...basically the tutorial I found was totally wrong.

DonMag's comments helped me to solve the issue.

```
// Instantiate the HogeDView from its Xib file
let hogeDView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("hogeDView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView

// Set the frame for the HogeDView
hogeDView.frame = self.view.bounds
        
// Add the HogeDView as a subview to the parent view
self.view.addSubview(hogeDView)
```

To Donmag, and HangarRash, thank you for giving me a feedback.